# Why is "struct pid" member `numbers` defined as an array of size 1?

Tags: linux, process, source-code

I noticed that, in `struct pid` in
[pid.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pid.h),
the member `numbers` is defined as an array of size 1.

```
struct pid
{
    refcount_t count;
    unsigned int level;
    spinlock_t lock;
    /* lists of tasks that use this pid */
    struct hlist_head tasks[PIDTYPE_MAX];
    struct hlist_head inodes;
    /* wait queue for pidfd notifications */
    wait_queue_head_t wait_pidfd;
    struct rcu_head rcu;
    struct upid numbers[1];
};
```

However, in [pid.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/pid.c#L244), the member is accessed with indices other than 0.

```
pid->numbers[i].nr = nr;
```

How does this work without writing out of bounds?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577094/array-of-size-0-at-the-end-of-struct

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I hadn't heard of the struct hack before.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of flexible arrays, albeit not using the now-standard syntax (which would be `struct upid numbers[];`). The general idea is that such structs are allocated with enough room for all the fields, plus enough room for the real size of the array at the end of the struct.

The structures are allocated in a cache; you can see the size calculation in [`create_pid_cachep`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/kernel/pid_namespace.c#L50):

```c
len = sizeof(struct pid) + level * sizeof(struct upid);
```

This allocates enough room for a `struct pid` at the given level (starting at 0, so with room for one `struct upid`).

`struct pid` itself has room for one element in its `numbers` array, because [the level-0 cache is allocated using `KMEM_CACHE`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/kernel/pid.c#L663), and that expects [a single struct representing a complete cache entry](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/include/linux/slab.h#L169).

Work has been going on for the last few years to switch all such array uses to standardised flexible arrays; for more information, see [Gustavo A. R. Silva’s recent talk on the Kernel Self-Protection Project](https://kernel-recipes.org/en/2022/talks/the-kernel-self-protection-project-and-how-you-can-help/) at Kernel Recipes 2022.